# nodejs telnet websocket response as <Buffer>

Tags: node.js, websocket, telnet

I am getting a telnet response as showed below when tried with nodejs code. Actually it is in xml format. When I did directly call the telnet response, the correct xml format is delivering. Can someone plz help, why 'Buffer' response when calling via nodejs.

"Buffer 3c 6e 66 6c 2d 65 76 65 6e 74 3e 0d 0a 20 3c 67 61 6d 65 63 6f 64 65 20
3 6f 64 65 3d 22 32 30 31 37 31 31 33 30 30 30 36 22 20 67 6c 6f 62 61 6c 2d .. "

Comment: Call `chunk.toString()` to get text value.

Comment: Thanks it worked!!!